# For the past month, I haven't been able to get this transaction to go through

Tags: transaction, wallet, pending

I have this transaction that won't go through, and because of address reuse, I'm not able to create any new transactions until I get this transaction to go through.

Before the newest version of the wallet came out, I tried reattaching and rebroadcasting this transaction, and then waiting a few days/weeks, and then trying again. I've tried attaching to multiple different nodes. Nothing I do is able to make my transaction go through. I've upgraded to the newest version of the wallet now, but still no luck.

If I reattach, and then promote, after 30 minutes or so, the promote option goes away, and I'm only able to reattach again. Is this normal?

This [answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/799/in-the-iota-wallet-what-does-the-promote-button-do?newreg=680e8e1d4d67429b8b8be512bad5336a) mentions bad stuff happening if a reattachment gets attached to a previous reattachment. I wonder if that is what is happening. How would I know if this is the problem?

Comment: Which wallet are you using platform-wise?

Comment: IOTA light wallet 2.5.6 IRI 1.4.1.6 on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to go through. I used [this tool](http://www.reattach.online/) to automatically promote/reattach every 30 minutes, and my transaction has been confirmed now.

Comment: Consider completing the question by selecting your answers as the right one.

Comment: I've accepted my answer now.